# Postgresql - human-readable aliases for numerical primary keys

Tags: postgresql

Like many databases, I have a table of people with a serial-generated numerical primary key, since names are not unique:

```
ID  NAME  STUFF
---------------
101  Bob     20
102  Bob     30
```

And several other tables reference these IDs as a foreign key:

```
ORDER  PERSON  NOTE
-------------------
1       02     Blah
2       01     Foo
```

(Can't use name instead of ID as FK since FKs must reference a column with a unique constraint). Since my data entry is manual, using a GUI (right now pgAdmin or LibreOffice on a Mac) it would be much easier to see a person's name instead of numerical ID when working on the order table. I've thought of a number of solutions to this seemingly simple problem and none seem good:

A) Views - not editable. I know [how to make views editable with triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) but AFAIK no GUI editor can use this to allow editable views.

B) Add a name column to Order table, then use triggers to keep everything in sync - it's tempting, but then I have duplicate data, and a headache when my table structure evolves. Somewhat better if the Order name column is enforced read-only with triggers, but still many pitfalls.

C) What I REALLY want is some way to toggle the GUI editor between displaying the person ID and the corresponding name, in whatever arbitrary tables they appear in, without compromising the underlying data integrity.

Hope this is clear; can provide more details if needed. Thanks for any help!

Comment: re a) how do you know that **no** GUI editor does that (btw: what exactly is a "GUI editor" for you?)

Comment: Thanks for replying... I don't know that for a fact, AFAIK = As Far As I Know. By GUI editor I mean that data entry is done using a graphical front end, such as the grid editor in pgAdmin or the table control in LibreOffice (I prefer a simple grid/spreadsheet-style editor). Rather than adding/updating data via the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this (at least on Windows) with Microsoft Access and the postgres ODBC driver. Steps are based on 2010, but the process is the same on 2003 and 2007.

1. Link your tables to a new Access database and set the relationships between them.
2. Open the table with the foreign key in design view and switch to design tab on the bottom.
3. Choose Combo box instead of Textbox.
4. Click on Query source then on the three dots on the right.
5. Add the table with the primary key to the query designer
6. Add the column what you want to see then the column with the ID
7. Close editor
8. Change Bound column to 2, since your second column is the key

Here you can find a small example based on your question: (without the ODBC though) https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D949685_2198453_6801553